# Adding reciprocal second x axis to Matlab plot

Tags: matlab

[image: Graph layout]Good afternoon SO,

I'm producing plots of (1 / temperature) against stuff, and would like to also add a temperature axis at the top of the graph to allow temperature ranges to be more readable. I found something called plotxx.m, but the problem I see is that the top axis isn't going to be a linear one, but a funky reciprocal scale. How could I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need a different axis, or is it sufficient to change the tick labels?

Comment: Could you share a piece of your code or make a drawing of what you are expecting to see?

Comment: Have edited to show my beautiful sketch of what i want - the upper axis isn't going to be linear..